# Simple commission calculation program causes infinite loop

Tags: python

I am attempting to run the following code, but it seems like i am getting some sort of infinite loop, but i am not using loops. I have attempted to rewrite the code but i can't understand what is wrong. How can i edit the code so that it doesn't run infinitely?

```
sales  = float(input('enter sales'))
comm_rate = float(input('enter rate'))
commission = sales * comm_rate
print('the commission is $', format(commission, ' .2f'), sep = '')
```

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Is there any more code that you wrote? For sure this isn't the part that is causing it to go in a loop.

Comment: What are you inputting when it prompts for sales and rate?

Comment: As it stands, this definitely requires additional detail about how it's being run to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is use `"{:.2f}".format(commission)` instead of `format(commission, ' .2f'), sep = ''`.

```
print('the commission is $', "{:.2f}".format(commission))
```

Comment: Or just `print(f"the commission is ${commission:.2f}")`.

Comment: You are right but this has nothing to do with the question about infinite loop...

Comment: If you add decimals for both inputs you can reproduce the error. Loop thing does not affect to round number inputs

Comment: @Kalana What numbers were you able to reproduce the issue with? Which version of python? I tried floating point numbers for both the `sales` and `comm_rate` but I do not see the issue happening

Comment: I used [online compiler](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/).